# Custom changePage on jquery mobile causes c.data("page") is undefined on second call

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, javascript

I'm trying to build some custom navigation in a dynamic application, all screens are obtained from the server and thus I registered the **pagebeforechange** event and execute my own function.

Everything works as I expected except when I refresh the data I destroy the dynamic pages and try to call the page I was in again using the page Id, but this second time, although my code creates the HTML for the page, jQuery Mobile throws an "*c.data("page") is undefined*" error.

I bind the pagebeforechange event:

```js
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if(typeof data.toPage === 'string') {
        appobj.dynamicPage(data.toPage, data.options);
    }
});
```

Then in the dynamicPage method I create the HTML for my page based on Underscore.js templates and let jQuery continue changing the page:

```js
$.get('templates/page.tpl.html', function (data) {
    html = _.template(data, { /* several template parameters */});
});

page = $(html);
page.appendTo('body').page();
```

The idea was to use as much of jQM as possible since I'm creating the destination page and injecting it into the DOM.

When I need to update the supporting data, that I store in localStorage, I just find all dynamic pages and destroy them:

```js
var current = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');

$('.dynamicpage').remove();

$.mobile.changePage('#' + current
```

When running the application I can easily navigate between various screens/pages, even for pages that don't exist when the application starts but if the data needs to be updated (because the user added elements in the application of data in the database changed) then the removal code is executed but the old page is not regenerated ending in a white page with all the DOM contents hidden, but the page I wanted to navigate too seems to be in the DOM (at least firebug tells me so).

If I were to restart development I would probably use Backbone.js to handle my model updates and view changes but for now I'll have to use only jQM. Any suggestions? I understand that jQM is not finding my page but I don't see why since my event should be called and the page regenerated, even with the **allowSamePageTransition** flag set.

Regards,

Sérgio Lopes